# Is this the best way to transform a string into an object in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The code below is working, however, I think it is a lot of coding. I am uncomfortable with this. Does someone know a more concise way to write this?

The main goal is extracting a sort param from a HTTP query and sort a Mongoose/Mongodb collection.

The sort query is `GET /flavors?sort=id ASC`, so, I took this string `["id", "ASC"]` in `sort` and transformed it in `{id : ASC}` in `sortStr`

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
      var { sort } = req.query;
      var v_fields = sort.split(",");
      var v_field = v_fields[0].replace('[', '');
      var v_order = v_fields[1].replace(']', '');
      var sortStr = `{ ${v_field} : ${v_order} }`;
      var re = new RegExp(`"`, 'g');
      sortStr = sortStr.replace(re, '');

      Flavor.find().sort(sortStr).then(result => {
...
}
```

Comment: If you changed the query to be `?sort=id&sort=ASC` I believe that `req.query.sort` would be `['id', 'ASC']` using body parser with a particular configuration. Might have to dig around, but that would probably be more robust than doing hand-written string manipulation to get the format you want.

Comment: Or IF you want to use an object then [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) can automatically handle it if you structure the query as such: `/flavors?sort[id]=ASC` and accessed via `req.query.sort` => `{id: 'ASC'}`.

Comment: @JasonCust very good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and your sort string always represents an array containing two elements, you could do something like this:

```
var s='["id", "ASC"]';
var arr=JSON.parse(s);
var sortObj={};
sortObj[arr[0]]=arr[1];
```

Comment: That is perfect, it worked and reduced a lot of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:

```
 const [key, order] = req.query.sort.split(" ");
 Flavor.find().sort({ [key]: order }).then(/*...*/);
```

Concerning your code:

1) `vfields` is an array, and the arrays elements do not contain any `[` or `]` in your example so there is no need to remove them.

2) sort expects an object, so you should pass an object not a string.

Comment: It does not work, when I extract the sort from the req it is a string representing an array, not an array. So, it has `[` and `]`